# Open specific accordion tab using external link and hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

hi to all I'm new in js sorry for what I ask here now I know its a basic one, I'm working now with accordion plugin that collects all the article that users want to put in accordion and view it in accordion my question is how to open specific tab when is have dynamic id per article inside a item of accordion.. im trying to hook the item using link, http//:example.com#id to open specific tab in accordion here s the plugin code.
hook inside the code and trigger the click event to open the specific the in the accordion plugin

!(function($){

```
$.fn.spAccordion = function(options){

    var settings = $.extend({
        hidefirst: 0
    }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

        var $items      = $(this).find('>div');
        var $handlers   = $items.find('.toggler');
        var $panels     = $items.find('.sp-accordion-container');

        if( settings.hidefirst === 1 )
        {
            $panels.hide().first();
        }
        else
        {
            $handlers.first().addClass('active');
            $panels.hide().first().slideDown();
        }

        $handlers.on('click', function(){

            if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
            {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $panels.slideUp();
            }
            else
            {
                $handlers.removeClass('active');
                $panels.slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('active').parent().find('.sp-accordion-container').slideDown();
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: You could make this question better by being more specific about what you want to know, or what's not working.

Comment: my apologize, greg the code above is working i wanted to hook in inside the code and to trigger the onclick event using hash in link thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

A little thing is, you can use `.children('div')` instead of `.find('>div')`.

But if you want to get what the hash is set to you can use `window.location.hash`. By default this is used to identify element IDs. So ideally you could get the element you want to show by doing

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var $selected = $('#'+window.location.hash);
    if ($selected.length) {
        // Do what you need to show this element
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @tal how can i pass the value of window.location.hash here s my sample url to open tab in accordion http://localhost/test/index.php/accordion-link-title#120 and to trigger the $handlers.on('click', function(){}?